# How do I pick up pics from a dead commander?

Tags: far-cry-4

How do I pick up Pics from a dead commanders body?

When I finish shooting a commander in a mission with a specific gun I get dog tags, and the yellow indicator still blinks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the bounty quests, you have to take your camera out and take a picture of the commander in question, after he is dead of course. that is sometimes part of the requirements to finish the bounty.